# Staying logged in to an Android App

Tags: android, authentication, autologin

I'm new to both java and the android so I apologize if I'm missing something obvious.

I'm trying to allow a user to stay logged in to an application. What is the best way to do this? Can anybody point me to a tutorial? I've searched the web and can't seem to find anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean logged in? Like the user has a login/pass to an external site that you are accessing through your app?  To do that you should save the data in the SharedPreferences for the app, and then on start-up you check the Preferences and then login for the user.

Comment: Yes, I mean logged in to an external website. I've found some great resources for SharedPreferences so I think I'm on the right track now. Thanks!